# Using REPE and SCASB in assembly language

Tags: assembly

when using SCASB and REPE instructions, how can we realize that the inequality has occurred in the last byte?
I mean, suppose that we are scanning a string for the byte. how can we show that the last byte of the string is not equal to the byte we are scanning for?

Comment: Unless you are actually using an 8086, there is no advantage in using these instructions. Current processors work faster if you write the loop using simple instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Simply said: Do an additional check on the last byte using plain old assembly instructions:

Load A
  Load B
  Compare
  Branch/Set Flag on condition

That's how it has been done for years.